# $html2pdf->Output('example.pdf', 'FI'); the file doesn't save in the right folder

Tags: html2pdf

Using html2pdf, i need to save the generated file.pdf in my folder (not the same than my file.php) AND display it on the screen with the same action.

- When i did $html2pdf->Output('example.pdf', true); i could display it
  well.
- When i did $html2pdf->Output('absolute/path/example.pdf', 'F'); i
  could save it well.
- But with    $html2pdf->Output('absolute/path/example.pdf', 'FI'),
  whick it    suppose to do the combination (true + F), i can display
  it and i can    save it but in the same folder than file.php and with
  this name :    absolutepathexample.pdf.

I did't find in the docs or in any other site an example with 'FI' used. Any idea ?

Comment: https://github.com/spipu/html2pdf/blob/master/doc/output.md#parameters: _"`I`: [...] The name given by `name` is used when one selects the "Save as" option on the link generating the PDF."_ - that is probably the reason it removes the slashes from the given path. Looks like using that `FI` combination it is not able to handle the name separately for those two contexts. But I suppose you should be able to simply call the output method two times - make it save under the desired name first, and then stream it to the browser via a second call afterwards ...?

Comment: Unfortunately no. Method F takes over and prevents display, even if I try to call a new html2pdf object

Comment: Maybe you can use [`chdir`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chdir.php) to switch your script's working directory to `/absolute/path/` first, then call `->Output('example.pdf', 'FI')` ...?